# How to find names of the files that have str1 and str2 in possibly in *different* parts of the file

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to find a way to determine the names of the files that have str1 and str2 possibly in different parts of the file.
grep str1 | grep str2 will not work since grep str2 will operation on the lines that contain str1.
I can get a list of files that contain str1 and again a list of files that contain str2 and then seek the intersection but that is inefficient.
A more efficient way is to make grep str1 output a list of files and then make grep str2 operate on that, but that means grep will be opening, reading and closing the same file over and over again.
Perhaps the most ideal way is to open a file,grep for str1 and str2 and then determine if the file contains both str1 and str2 but I am not able to create such a command.
I guess it should look similar to this find . -name "*" -exec grep "str1" && grep "str2" {} \;   but this is not syntactically correct

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk (gawk):

```
awk -v RS='\0' -v str1="$str1" -v str2="$str2" '
   index($0,str1) && index($0,str2) { print FILENAME; nextfile }
' file1 file2 filen
```

With any awk:

```
awk -v str1="$str1" -v str2="$str2" '
   FNR == 1             { found[1] = found[2] = 0 }
   index($0,str1)       { found[1]++ }
   index($0,str2)       { found[2]++ }
   found[1] && found[2] { files[FILENAME] }
   END { for (file in files) print file }
' file1 file2 filen
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment on the

> make grep str1 output a list of files and then make grep str2 operate on that

solution make it sounds much worse than it actually is: every file will be opened at least once by the first `grep` and every file that *does* contain str1 will be opened a second time by the second `grep`. Not that bad and certainly not “opening, reading and closing the same file over and over again”. Maximum twice, sometimes only once. If you are after more efficiency, I can probably give you an answer based on `perl` but it is probably not worth the trouble. Do you *actually* have troubles opening a file twice?

## A solution that opens some files twice

The `-l` argument to `grep` gives you *only* the names of the files. Thus `grep -l str1 files…` will list all the files that have `str1` somewhere inside. Then repeat with `str2`. The result will be something like:

```
grep -l str1 files… | xargs grep -l str2 /dev/null
```

The `/dev/null` at the end is a trick so that if there is *no* file matching `str1` then the second `grep` is not stuck reading on `stdin`.

If you are using GNU grep and findutils then you will be safer with the `-Z` and `-0` options to `grep` and `xargs`.

```
grep -lZ str1 files… | xargs -r0 grep -l str2
```

Comment: In this solution each file with str1 will be opened twice. Author wants only one open&close for every file.

Answer (score 0):

I think awk is better suited for this task. Here's one way you could do it:

```
awk -v str1="$str1" -v str2="$str2" '
  FNR == 1 { m1 = m2 = 0 }
  index($0, str1) { m1 = 1 }
  index($0, str2) { m2 = 1 }
  m1 && m2 { print FILENAME; nextfile }' file1 file2 filen
```

This assumes that `$str1` and `$str2` are set to the strings you want to search for. The solution does the match in one pass and exits as soon as both strings have been found.

A slightly optimized version:

```
awk -v str1="$str1" -v str2="$str2" '
  FNR == 1 { m1 = m2 = 0 }
  !m1 && index($0, str1) { m1 = 1 }
  !m2 && index($0, str2) { m2 = 1 }
  m1 && m2 { print FILENAME; nextfile }' file1 file2 filen
```

#### Update:

Added the bugfixes and optimizations mentioned by *Ed Morton* in the comments below. Also note that there may be some portability issues with the `nextfile` statement in older versions of awk, see this discussion of the subject in the [GNU awk appendix B](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Versions). The `nextfile` statement has been [accepted for inclusion](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607) in the  POSIX standard, so should be even more widely available in the future.

Comment: The `exit` makes it impossible to process more than one matching file at a time. It should not be too hard to refactor this so it can process a list of file arguments instead of just a single file argument.

Comment: @tripleee: of course, I should have used `nextfile`, will add it shortly.

Comment: note that when you use nextfile you're making it GNU-awk-only. Also, what you're doing it matching an RE, not a string so if "str1" contained "a.c" that would match "abc", etc. not just the literal "a.c" - you should be using index() instead of match() or ~.

Comment: the above also needs to reset m1 and m2 or once they get set the first time they will stay set for the rest of the files.

Comment: @EdMorton: Right, I wasn't happy about the RE matching either, just didn't think of the `index()` function, thank you; and of course the match-flags need to be reset. `nextfile` is supported by current versions of gawk and nawk and will be in mawk version 1.4 (at least according to [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/sedawk/ch11_02.htm)), but yes it's not completely portable; the [gawk manual lists a workaround](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_174.html).

Comment: $Thor - thanks for the tip on other awks that support nextfile. You can't reset m1 and m2 where you currently do as that can leave one of them set from one file to the next. Imagine what would happen if m1 gets set while parsing file1 and m2 gets set in file2.

Comment: @EdMorton: You're welcome, I was surprised to find that nextfile was such a recent feature though. You're right of course about the resetting of m1 and m2, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use regexp like `(str1.*str2|str2.*str1)`. I'm not sure, may be you will need to use `egrep` instead of `grep`

Comment: This will not work when str1 and str2 are not on the same line.

Comment: @pstr: If think `grep -Ezl 'str1.*str2|str2.*str1'` is what the OP is after.

Answer (score -2):

If str1 occurs before str2 then you can use

```
find . -name "str1*str2"
```

Comment: -1 This is not about files whose names match, it's files whose contents match.